# my function does not work and i cant find out why iv ben doing reserch for a few hours and havent ben able to corect whatever mistake iv made

Tags: lua, computercraft

I have been trying to make a function in lua with computercraft. but every time I try loading it as an API it says {attempt to index?( nil value)}

```
function toggleBundledColor(side, color)
    applied = rs.getBundledOutput(side)
    if applied == 0 then
        rs.setBundledOutput(side,color)
    elseif applied ~= color and 0 then
        rs.setBundledOutput(side, colors.combine(applied, color))
    elseif applied == color then
        rs.setBundledOutput(side, colors.subtract(applied,color))
    end
end
```

I have been to the wiki of computercraft and looked at multiple posts on there sites and have found no solution to what I've done wrong

Comment: The error would suggest you are trying to get the value of some table element that does not exist...are you sure "rs" (I'm assuming stands for redstone) is valid and that it contains those methods? You can use a for loop and print the contents of that table to check.

Comment: yes i am sure as it works its just the moment i try making somthing like this it dosnt work anymore for some reasn. if i put rs.setBundledOutput(side, white) [just as an example] and then run it then it sets the color white ass expected so rs definetly is a thing. and how would i do a for loop print?

Comment: for k, v in pairs(rs) do
    print(k, v)
end

Answer (score 1):

I see you have a variable set as `aplied` and you have referenced `applied` (once with a double `p`) which won't refer to the original variable `aplied` (with a single `p`). so `applied` is a `nil value` since it isn't set to anything.

related line of code for your reference:

```py
elseif aplied ~= color and 0 then
        rs.setBundledOutput(side, colors.combine(-->applied<--, color))
```

Comment: M bbas Haider Taqvi i changed it and tested but it stil does not work so that isnt the only problem aperently

Comment: please provide the errors

Comment: i have put the only error i got thats literly the error the nil value